# How can I copy a 2D Array inside an object in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've defined a class as follows:

```
Public class Board{
    public static final int SIZE = 4;
    private static char[][] matrix = new char[SIZE][SIZE];

    public Board(){
        clear();//just fills matrix with a dummy character
    }

    public void copy(Board other){//copies that into this
        for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++){
                matrix[i][j] = other.matrix[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    //a bunch of other methods
}
```

So here's my problem: when I try to make a copy, like `myBoard.copy(otherBoard)`, any changes made to one board affect the other. I copied in individual primitive elements, and yet the reference to `matrix` is the same for both Boards. I thought I was copying elements, why are the pointers the same? What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 5):

`matrix` is `static` so all the `Board` objects share the same.

Remove the `static` to have each `Board` have its own matrix.

```
private static char[][] matrix = new char[SIZE][SIZE];   <-- Because of this line
matrix[i][j] = other.matrix[i][j];                       <-- These two are the same.
```

Comment: Thank you, I feel ridiculous. My CS teacher isn't stellar, but you are

Comment: @LeoShwartz Thank you but it's too much honor. ;D

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
private static char[][] matrix = new char[SIZE][SIZE];
```

to

```
private char[][] matrix = new char[SIZE][SIZE];
```

`static` means that there is only one instance of this array.